Why are mouseDown an mouseUp events not scheduling the same animationFrame?
Here is a sample code, shown that mouseUp and mouseDown result in 2 different animation frames even when doing a simple click.
const d = document.createElement('div');
const b = document.createElement('button');
b.textContent = 'Click me!';

b.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button mousedown'));
  console.log('button mousedown');
});

b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button click'));
  console.log('button click');
});

b.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button mouseup'));
  console.log('button mouseup');
});

document.body.appendChild(d);
d.appendChild(b);

let timerId;
function schedule(cb) {
  if (timerId === undefined) {
    timerId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      console.log('running synchronization');
      timerId = undefined;
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz demo.
It logs :
button mousedown
running synchronization
button mouseup
button click
running synchronization

Can someone point me to an authoritative answer to why they are systematicaly scheduling different frames even if the event is not a long click. (It would make sense in a long click context).

Animation frame frequency is 60Hz (16,666msecs), typical time from mousedown to mouseup is 100 - 150 msecs.

@Teemu requestAnimationFrame is not bound to 60Hz.

Right, that's the lowest frequency. OS interupts can slow the ratio down, but that typically (by my experience) multiplies the time between the calls with 4 - 5 at maximum. This is very OS and system state dependent, of course.

There is nothing special going on in here. The action is just slower than your monitor's refresh rate (typically 60Hz, which is 16.7ms per frame), which is not much compared to the mechanical action of releasing the button's connector from its pressed state. Add to this the possible poll rate limitation of your mouse (typically 125Hz for a wireless office mouse, can go up a lot if you have an USB gaming mouse) and it becomes almost impossible to perform this in less than a monitor frame, even if we lower it down.
Then we can cheat. requestAnimationFrame isn't completely tied to the monitor's refresh rate, and if we lock the event loop long enough, we can get both events to queue in the same animation frame.
In below snippet we show the count of frames that elapsed between both events, and we allow locking the event loop for 300ms to show that there is nothing forcing a new animation frame to fire between these.


const locker = document.querySelector("input");
const b = document.querySelector("button");
b.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button mousedown'));
  if (locker.checked) {
    const t1 = performance.now();
    while (performance.now() - t1 < 300) {}
  }
  console.log('button mousedown');
});

b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button click'));
  console.log('button click');
});

b.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  schedule(() => console.log('schedule button mouseup'));
  console.log('button mouseup');
  console.log("frames elapsed: ", count);
  running = false;
  count = 0;
});

let running = false;
let timerId;
let count = 0;
function schedule(cb) {
  if (timerId === undefined) {
    running = true;
    timerId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      console.log('running synchronization');
      timerId = undefined;
    });
  }
}
// An ever running animation loop that increments our counter
// when the running flag is on
const anim = () => {
  if (running) {
    count++;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
};
anim();
<label>Lock event loop in mousedown <input type=checkbox></label><br>
<button>click me</button>



Ps: running this snippet on a touch device you may have a zero count even without locking the event loop.
